# about php str_replace function

Tags: php, str-replace

Here is my code:

```
$search = array('<script src="/',
        '<link href="/',
        '<a href="/',
        '<img src="/',
        'src="/');
$d = 'http://www.ifreewind.net';
$replace = array('<script src="'.$d.'/',
         '<link href="'.$d.'/',
         '<a href="'.$d.'/',
         '<img src="'.$d.'/',
         'src="'.$d.'/');
$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $contents);

echo $result;
```

These code have a problem is that they cannot replace `img` tag such as :

```
<img width="50px" src="/...">
```

into

```
<img width="50px" src="http://www.ifreewind.net/...">
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `str_replace` for this. You could try it with `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace('~(src|href)="(?=/)~', '$1http://www.ifreewind.net', $contents);
```

However, I'd strongly advise you to use [an HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.